# Rewriting seo-url to url with query string

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to use mod_rewrite to do urls like this:

http://domain.tld/id/1/type/2/url/http://domain2.tld

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you want the url to become after the re-write?  This is critical information to know how to craft the mod_rewrite rule.

Comment: @Chris I have an api like this: api.php?uid=1&args=1&url=http://domain.tld and I want to use mod_rewrite for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/+id/([^/]*)/type/([^/]*)/url/(http://)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /api.php?uid=%1&type=%2&url=%3%4 [L,NE]
```

This will support both `/id/1/type/2/url/http://domain2.tld` and `/id/1/type/2/url/domain2.tld` URIs.

Answer (score 0):

Now we're in business!  Create an `.htaccess` file, then add these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^id/(.*)/type/(.*)/url/http:/(.*)$   api.php?uid=$1&type=$2&url=$3 [L]
```

Note that this will end up passing `domain2.tld` as the `url` parameter - you'll have to add the "http://" back on yourself.  As we've discussed in comments, you're better off with properly formed URLs using `urlencode`, but if that isn't an option, this will do.

There is no dearth of information on `mod_rewrite` on the internet. Here's a blog: http://www.htmlist.com/how-to/a-simplemod_rewrite-tutorial/ - just one of many results if you search for "mod_rewrite" on the Google.

Comment: I have already tried this but don't work. After url/ i need to uset http: //domain.tld and this don't work.

Comment: A) I don't understand what you mean by "uset http: //domain.tld and this don't work", and B) it would be nice if you had included what you have already attempted so we don't **waste our time** suggesting things that you've already tried.  The principles in this snippet of htaccss work - I took it straight out of a working htaccss file on my own site.  :)  Edit your question and include ALL the relevant details, including what you have already tried.

Comment: I have a link like this api.php?uid=1&args=1&url=http: //domain.tld (without space between http: and //) and I want to rewrite this link but with ^id/(.*)/type/(.*)/url/(.*)$ the last syntax don't work, my php don't get $3. Without mod_rewrite all is fine, but with mode rewrite don't work $3 (&url=$3). I don't know how to explain more.

Comment: The trouble might be that it isn't valid to pass a non-url-encoded URL as a query string parameter.  That `url=` portion needs to be encoded, so `http://domain2.tld` needs to be `http%3A%2F%2Fdomain2.tld`.  The reason that the mod_rewrite rule is failing is because of the unencoded forward slashes. See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: I understand but look at this, they can do that: http://zpag.es/api/4947102a15cb93454e1c7d76c130f83a/uid/5892/domain/zpag.es/z_t/pa/url/http://somewebsite.com

Comment: You could also try this rule: `RewriteRule ^id/(.*)/type/(.*)/url/http:/(.*)$  api.php?uid=$1&type=$2&url=$3 [L]`, a little hacky, but it will pass everything after `http://` as the URL parameter.  Tested working, updated answer.